# How do I solve $yy''=y'-5y$ given that $y(1)=1$ and $y'(1)=-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $yy''=y'-5y$ given that $y(1)=1$ and $y'(1)=-1$?
Do I have to integrate both sides of ODE?
$$yy''=y'-5y$$
$$y''=\frac{y'}{y}-5$$
$$\int{y''dx}=\int{(\frac{y'}{y}-5)dx}$$
$$y'=\int{(\frac{y'}{y}-5)dx}$$
I have a problem with the last integral.
What would be the best (easiest) approach for solving this ODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceeding with what you've done

$$y' = \int \left(\frac{y'}{y}-5\right) dx$$

$$y' = \ln y -5x + c$$
 I've tried to obtain a closed form solution using Maple 16 but to no avail. I was only able to get a graph of the solution within that range. Maple tells that there may perhaps be a singularity preventing me from evaluating it further.

[image]

Comment: Since $y$ is a function of $x$, you can't say that $$\int \ln y \ dx = x \ln y.$$

Comment: The second integration is incorect.